# Make column unique in two tables in our database

Tags: oracle

I have come into a bump at my current company where they have an account and a member.  For some reason or another both are stored in separate tables.

Right now a member and an account can be registered. That's fine, except the users of both member and an account can have the same username.  This is of course as you all know just wrong. Especially since they use the username to login to the same system except with different functionality levels.

Right now we are doing a check at the application level, and we're just wondering if it's possible to get the database to enforce two columns to be unique, say like a union of the two tables.

Can't set them up as primary or foreign key at the moment but that's for future anyway.  Right now looking for a quick fix. In the future I will probably merge databases and get all members added on as new rows in the account table and add a boolean for IsMember.

Comment: I would say until you can fix the db design issue properly, don't impose more patches to the db layer, just stick with the app checks you already have.

Comment: @tbone I disagree. If you can add a check that ensures less problems in the future you should do it.

Comment: @Jens my issue is this: The right thing to do is fix the design issue.  Instead, this person will start adding triggers or who knows what to maintain a poor design.  These "temporary fixes" often become permanent.  Rinse and repeat and you have yourself a mess.

Comment: How are accounts disabled ? hard or soft delete ?

Comment: soft delete so they can be renable if wanted, if user wants us to remove information completely we do a hard delete.

Comment: if soft deleted then that username remains unique to that user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, I agree with the consensus opinion that it's better to fix the design than to kluge a fix using triggers. However, a properly implemented trigger-based solution is still probably better than your current situation.

If you're going to use triggers, the right way to do it is to:

1. Create a new table that will contain nothing but usernames, with a primary key enforcing uniqueness (this may, in fact, be a good candidate for an indes-organized table).
2. Create before-insert triggers on both existing tables that add the new username to the new table. If the new username already exists, an error will be thrown, preventing the insert of both rows. Of course, the application will need to be able to handle this error gracefully (presumably it already can, for scenarios in which the new username already exists in the table it's being added to).

The wrong way to do this would be to make the trigger select from the other table, in order to verify uniqueness.

Comment: Yeah Klas I would of accepted yours but he just expanded upon the question nicely in his answer. thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah, I don't always have the time/energy to elaborate on my answers. Accepting Allan's answer will aid future readers more, so you did the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `trigger` that enforces your requirement.

Comment: The correct(tm) way would be to fix the design, as tbone says. A trigger-based solution can be made to work (for instance, by letting the triggers update a new table that has user name as PK). It is awkward, yes, but it works as long as no one else modifies the new table.

Comment: I agree a (temporary) trigger solution will work, simply add a new disabled record to the other table.

Answer (score 1):

As you use a soft delete pattern.
A trigger could be used (on each table) as a temporary measure.

By inserting a disabled record in the the other table, you will get a failure if the other record already exists

Remember this will not enforce the rule on existing data, only records that are inserted will be checked

Something like this:

```
-- Insert into the accounts table too
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_member_chk 
BEFORE INSERT ON members
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO account (name, id, etc, isenabled) VALUES(:new.name, :new.id, :new.etc, 0);
END;

-- Insert into the members table too
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_account_chk 
BEFORE INSERT ON accounts
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO members (name, id, etc,isenabled) VALUES(:new.name, :new.id, :new.etc,0);
END;
```

Comment: The triggers won't raise an exception when two session insert the same value in the two tables before they both commit.

Comment: good point... have updated to take into account the soft delete pattern, and solve any concurrency issues.

Comment: Good alternative will also forward to team :D.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended triggers tend to be really brittle with concurrent transaction.

What you can do (AFAIK) is to create a materialized view containing the union of the column in question and put a unique constraint on that column.

Make sure you do some performance tests though.

Comment: unless they are used to simply insert into the other table (note a soft delete pattern used).